# Accessing values from appsettings.json in the Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core project that I am trying to run from VS. I am trying to access values from appsettings.json

Let's say I have this value in appsettings.json

```
"Heading": 
{
  "Path": "url"
}
```

And I am trying to get that value in Startup.cs

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    string path = Configuration["Heading:Path"];
   }
```

This comes up null.  Am I not accessing it properly?

The Program.cs has the following...

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: 
true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: 
true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
```

Comment: That should be correct. How are you running your program, from VS or VS Code, or from command line? Is the file called `appsettings.json` (you have a typo in your post), is there a Developer override file?

Comment: we need to see your program.cs file and also the settings file should be like { "Heading" :{"Path": "URL" } }

Comment: Based on your code, I have created an Asp.net 5 application, it seems that the code works well, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe8yi.gif). More detail information about configuration, you could refer [Default configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#default-configuration).

Comment: I actually figured out what was going on.  You  have to access it this way...Configuration["AppConfig:Heading:Path"]

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, I just tried it myself and both path variables are set to "url".

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  _configuration = configuration;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  string path = _configuration.GetSection("Heading:Path").Value;
  string path2 = _configuration["Heading:Path"];
}
```

The appsettings.json should look like this (maybe missing the outer brackets?):

```
{
  "Heading": {
    "Path": "url"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah my code is in the ConfigureServices() method which only takes the IServiceCollection.    It cannot take any other parameters.

Comment: you can just inject the IConfiguration interface in the constructor as i did it in my answer and use it in the ConfigureService method, the appsettings.json is getting injected by default.

Comment: Let us see your whole startup class.

Comment: Did you add the appsetting.json file manually (I mean you created the json file), If yes you'll need to set it to copy to the debug or release folder from your csproj. If you are using Visual Studio you can right-click the file in solution explorer and click on properties and select Copy to Output Directory to set it as Copy always or Copy if newer